# Django CSRF cookie not set error with React + Redux + Axios. Even though I added it to headers

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

I am using Django with React. I am fetching the csrf token from Django using `get_token()` method from `from django.middleware.csrf import get_token`.

I am passing it while making post request from React using Axios. Here is the code

```
return await Client.post(endpoint, {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + getState().auth.accessToken,
                "X-CSRFToken": getState().auth.csrf,
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            data,
        });
```

I am getting this error on my backend

`Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.):`

I then tried to add cookie in the headers...

```
headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + getState().auth.accessToken,
    "X-CSRFToken": getState().auth.csrf,
    "Cookie": getState().auth.csrf
},
```

Still don't work

Here is csrf setting in `settings.py`

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "localhost:3000",
]
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

Comment: Can you post your template code and if you're seeing a hidden input field in your form with a csrf token?

Comment: I am using react. I am fetching the token from`get_token()` `from django.middleware.csrf import get_token`and store it inside state